# How to pass the contents of a file as parameters in ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, parameter-passing, processbuilder

I want to pass a the contents of a .dat file as parameters in [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). How do I do this?

The .dat file contains:

```
08/10/12 4546.4 4644.5 6465.4 3 6.546 core dia,WH,C/C,no of steps,SF 0054.0 0005.0 005.00 0006.0 0006.0 066.00 0006.0 0006.0 006.00 leg width,yoke width,1/2 section step thk-Biggest size
```

I want to pass the content of the file as parameters in following code

```
 ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("E:\\MyFile.exe");
```

Comment: Are you looking to pass the *contents* or the *location* of the file as a parameter?

Comment: Post your code so that we may know about what you have tried and help us to solve.

Comment: i want to pass the content of the file as parameter because i dont have fixed no of argument

Answer (score 1):

```
FileReader r = null;
try {
    r = new FileReader(pathToDatFile);
    char[] buf = new char[50000]; // Or whatever is a good max length.
    int len = r.read(buf);
    String content = new String(buf, 0, len);
    String[] params = content.split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> invocation = new ArrayList<String>();
    invocation.add("E:\\MyFile.exe");
    invocation.addAll(Arrays.asList(params));
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(invocation);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle me!
} finally {
   try { r.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* handle me! */ }
}
```

Also: what encoding is your .dat file in? If it's not ASCII, you have to go via FileInputStream -> InputStreamReader so you can set the correct encoding in InputStreamReader. Otherwise, your code will use whatever the default is on the computer it happens to run on, with entertainingly inconsistent results!

Comment: what if the .dat file is not in one line.... it gives me Error    "Error while setting up environment for the application. Choose 'Close' to terminate the application"

Comment: I've edited the answer to just read in up to 50 kB of text. Question: do you mean to supply the entire contents as one single parameter, or should each bit of space-separated text be its own parameter?

Comment: entire content is not a single parameter, there are space-separated between the parameters

Comment: Right, I've updated it to split it into multiple parameters, and also edited your question to reflect that you meant multiple params. If the code doesn't quite work, you'll have to look at the precise contents of the file - are you using newlines to separate some params? Is there always exactly one space as a separator?